# Database Bottleneck In Distributed Application

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, distributed-computing, soa

I hear about SOA and Distributed Applications everywhere now. I would like know about some best practices related to keeping the single data source responsive or in case if you have copy of data on every server how it is better to synchronise those databases to keep them updated ?

Answer (score 3):

There are many answers to this question and in order to choose the most appropriate solution, you need to carefully consider what kind of data you are storing and what you want to do with it.

Replication

This is the traditional mechanism for many RDBMS, and normally relies on features provided by the RDBMS. Replication has a latency which means although servers can handle load independently, they may not necessarily be reading the latest data. This may or may not be a problem for a particular system. When replication is bidirectional then simultaneous changes on two databases can lead to conflicts that need resolving somehow. Depending on your data, the choice might be easy (i.e. audit log => append both), or difficult (i.e. hotel room booking - cancel one? select alternative hotel?). You also have to consider what to do in the event that the replication network link is down (i.e. do you deny updates on both database, one database or allow the databases to diverge and sort out the conflicts later). This is all dependent on the exact type of data you have. One possible compromise, for read-heavy systems, is to use unidirectional replication to many databases for reading, and send all write operations to the source database. This is always a trade-off between Availability and Consistency (see [CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)). The advantage of RDBMS and replication is that you can easily query your entire dataset in complex ways and have greater opportunity to 
remove duplication by using relational links to data items.

Sharding

If your data can be cleanly partitioned into disjoint subsets (e.g. different customers), such that all possible relational links between data items are contained within each subset (e.g. customers -> orders). Then you can put each subset in separate databases. This is the principle behind NoSQL databases, or as Martin Fowler calls them '[Aggregate-Oriented Databases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qI_g07C_Q5I)'. The downside of this approach is that it requires more work to run queries over your entire dataset, as you have to query all your databases and then combine the results (e.g. map-reduce). Another disadvantage is that in separating your data you may need to duplicate some (e.g. sharding by customers -> orders might mean product data is duplicated). It is also hard to manage the data schema as it lies independently on multiple databases, which is why most NoSQL databases are schema-less.

Database-per-service

In the microservice approach, it is advised that each microservice should have its own dedicated database, that is not allowed to be accessed by any other microservice (of a different type). Hence, a microservice that manages customer contact information stores the data in a separate database from the microservice that manages customer orders. Links can be made between the databases using globally unique ids, or URIs (especially if the microservices are RESTful) etc. The downside again from this is that it is even harder to perform complex queries on the entire dataset (especially since all access should go via the microservice API not direct to the databases).

Polyglot storage

So many of my projects in the past have involved a single RDBMS in which all data was placed. Some of this data was well suited to the relational model, much of it was not. For example, hierarchical data might be better stored in a graph database, stock ticks in a column-oriented database, html templates in a NoSQL database. The trend with micro-services is to move towards a model where different parts of your dataset are placed in storage providers that are chosen according to the need.

Answer (score 0):

If you thinking to keep different copies of the database for each microservice and you want to achieve eventual consistency than you can use Kafka Connect. I can briefly tell you that kafka connect will watch your DBS and whenever there are any changes it will read the log file and will add these logged events as a message in Queue then another database those are a subscriber to this Queue can execute the same statement at their side also.
Kafka connect isn't the only framework, you can search and find other frameworks or application for the same implementation.